# Is it possible to move pages from one Module to other Module

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a fully developed WPF/PRISM Application. There are four modules in it with separate regions for each of the four modules. There is a new requirement as to move some of the pages from each of the modules to a separate module. 
Now, I have created a separate module in the application. But have not started moving the pages from one module to this new module. Can someone tell me the challenges involved in this task? I am not sure of this as this is my first task in PRISM Application.

Answer (score 1):

On a first instance, I would verify that the **View** and **ViewModel** pages you are trying to move would be properly decoupled, i.e *resolving View instances with interface from the container*. Otherwise, you would face some build errors.

Nevertheless, you could perform the pages migration and fix the issues on a straight forward manner. Main considerations would be the following:

- **View** page moved with its corresponding **ViewModel**.
- New and modified modules initialization would be updated regarding moved pages.
- The bootstrapper would need to register the new module.

I hope you find this helpful,

Regards.